# Using NGINX to provide information to a server is a malpractice?

Tags: nginx, web-applications, architecture, system

**The Context:**
The system I'm developing consists in getting room readings which would start when a user pushes a button on a web dashboard.

The sensors (MQTT Clients) are connected to a dedicated AP emitted from a PC (Hub) at the room.

Sensors send the readings to the Hub (which would run a NGINX instance).

The Hub is connected to the "building" intranet.

The Hub then sends those readings to server (MQTT Broker + Flask App + SvelteKit App, dockerized etc...) which stores them in a DB.

This is a VERY stripped down version of the expected behavior:

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otz5u.png)

**The Problem:**
When looking at the diagram, at the 5th 'interaction', the Flask app should know the room id but so far I managed to keep the server stateless and I need to keep it that way.

**The Approach:**
The Hub is the only one that has information about the room id, the sensors already get that info from the NGINX#2 instance so I thought of 'intercepting' the browser HTTP POST request and sending a request with the room id to the flask app. (Hub are sure to be fix on every room)

Is this a good approach? Is a malpractice? Thanks.

*I don't know if the question title expresses the problem properly.*

Comment: It is better to upload the diagram image directly into the question.

Comment: I'm not allowed to embeed images in posts yet, I need a minimum of 10 rep ._. @Ibrahim